# Did Umbridge know when to come in to her office to interrupt Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry stupidly goes into Umbridge's office to talk to Sirius, he gets very rudely interrupted.

But did Umbridge know when to come into her office? If so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Umbridge herself reveals this, although it was pure coincidence that she caught Harry using the fireplace:

> "You think," she whispered, bending Harry's neck back even further, so that he was looking up at the ceiling, "that after two Nifflers I was going to let one more foul, scavenging little creature enter my office without my knowledge? I had Stealth Sensoring Spells placed all around my doorway after the last one got in, you foolish boy.
>
> <sup>*Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 32: "Out of the Fire"</sup>